# Writing custom Lombok Annotation handlers

Tags: java, lombok

I want to write custom Lombok Annotation handlers. I know http://notatube.blogspot.de/2010/12/project-lombok-creating-custom.html. But the current lombok jar file does not contain many .class files, but files named .SCL.lombok instead.

I found, the .SCL.lombok files are the .class files, the build script of Lombok does rename them while generating the jar file, and the [ShadowClassLoader](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/launch/lombok/launch/ShadowClassLoader.java) is capable of loading these classes -- and the acronym SCL seems to come from this. It seems the reason for this is just to "Avoid contaminating the namespace of any project using an SCL-based jar. Autocompleters in IDEs will NOT suggest anything other than actual public API."

I was only able to compile my custom handler by

- unpacking the contents of the lombok.jar
- renaming the .SCL.lombok files to .class
- adding the resulting directory to the compile classpath

In addition, to be able to use my custom handler, I needed to create a new fat jar containing both the lombok classes and my custom handler. The custom lombok class loader essentially prevents adding custom handlers in other multiple jars.

Is this the only way to extend Lombok? Or am I missing something?

I am using the following buildscript

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    lombok
    compileOnly
}

def unpackedAndRenamedLombokDir = file("$buildDir/lombok")

task unpackAndRenameLombok {
    inputs.files configurations.lombok
    outputs.dir unpackedAndRenamedLombokDir
    doFirst {
        mkdir unpackedAndRenamedLombokDir
        delete unpackedAndRenamedLombokDir.listFiles()
    }
    doLast {
        copy {
            from zipTree(configurations.lombok.singleFile)
            into unpackedAndRenamedLombokDir
            rename "(.*)[.]SCL[.]lombok", '$1.class'
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
        output.dir(unpackedAndRenamedLombokDir, builtBy: unpackAndRenameLombok)
    }
}

tasks.compileJava {
    dependsOn unpackAndRenameLombok
}

dependencies {
    compile files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
    compile "org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core:3.10.0"
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    lombok 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'

    compileOnly files(unpackedAndRenamedLombokDir)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the meantime Reinier Zwitserloot created a new git-branch [sclExpansionUpdate](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/tree/sclExpansionUpdate), that contains an updated version of the [ShadowClassLoader](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/commit/eb09843cce285caecd25e1a459e95d8c28dda417):

> ShadowClassLoader is now friendlier to trying to extend lombok.
>
> Your (separate) jar/dir should have a file named
>   META-INF/ShadowClassLoader. This file should contain the string
>   'lombok'. If you have that, any classes in that jar/dir will be loaded
>   in the same space as lombok classes. You can also rename the class
>   files to .SCL.lombok to avoid other loaders from finding them.

I guess this did not yet make it into the main branch because it certainly has not  been tested that much - I just tried it out for myself and it contains a little bug that prevents loading the required META-INF/services from extensions. To fix it you should replace two method calls to `partOfShadow` with `inOwnBase`:

```
[... line 443]
Enumeration<URL> sec = super.getResources(name);
while (sec.hasMoreElements()) {
    URL item = sec.nextElement();
    if (!inOwnBase(item, name)) vector.add(item); // <<-- HERE
}

if (altName != null) {
    Enumeration<URL> tern = super.getResources(altName);
    while (tern.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL item = tern.nextElement();
        if (!inOwnBase(item, altName)) vector.add(item); // <<-- AND HERE
    }
}
```

I tested it with the above fix and it seems to work fine (not tested much though).

On a side note: with this new extension mechanism, it is now finally also possible to have the extensions annotation handlers and annotations in a different namespace than "lombok" - nice!

Comment: More than 2 years have passed, is it still necessary to replace those two method calls to partOfShadow() with inOwnBase()? partOfShadow() method seems to delegate the bulk of work to inOwnBase() so I fail to see the benefit of this change. If it is needed, then why?

Comment: There is now a pull request for fixing the bug in ShadowClassLoader https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/2204

Comment: And the fix has been released, part of Lombok ver 1.18.10

Answer (score 2):

Using the input from this question and from the other answer (by Balder), we managed to put together a custom Lombok annotation handler: [Symbok](https://github.com/sympower/symbok/). Feel free to use that as a sample for writing your own.

BTW, instead of writing a custom Lombok handler, you could also implement a [javac plugin instead](https://www.baeldung.com/java-build-compiler-plugin) -- it might be simpler.