# How to import lombok JavacAnnotationHandler for a custom annotation?

Tags: java, lombok, annotation-processing

I am trying to follow this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41318338/2489463) to create my own custom annotation. However I cannot import `JavacAnnotationHandler`. I have had a look at the lombok 1.18.2 jar and the file it contains is: `lombok/javac/JavacAnnotationHandler.SCL.lombok`.

How can I import this in my java class?

Answer (score 7):

The only way to extend lombok is to fork the project, add it there, and then build your own lombok.jar. Lombok 'hides' most of its code so that it doesn't show up in, for example, your IDE autocomplete dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After 4 years, there is still no solution for this. Check this conversation for updates: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1068

Comment: It's open source; if you want a solution, write it, send a PR.

Comment: I forgot I even answered this - a new question has been asked with a considerably more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73175224/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok-1-16-8/73175565?noredirect=1)