# how to create like lombok annotation @getter?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I want to create an annotation(=@MyGetter) that does this

```java
@MyGetter
public class AnyClass {

    private String fieldVariable;

}
```

convert to (on compile)

```java
@MyGetter
public class AnyClass {

    private String fieldVariable;

    public String getFieldVariable() {
        if (isHexString()) {
            return ... // process
        }
        return fieldVariable
    }
}
```

In short, I want to create a getter that returns a string according to a specific condition when I put the annotation I made.

how can create this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create custom annotation for Lombok 1.16.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73175224/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok-1-16-8)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JavaAnnotationProcessor` to parse the custom annotation and generate the target code while compiling.