# Generating POJO for Parameterized JUnit test inputs

Tags: java, junit, lombok

I'm trying to find a way to generate a POJO object from the constructor of a class tagged with the `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` annotation. The POJO would be used to generate the `Object[]` used as inputs for the constructor. Does something like this already exist? If not how could I create it?

Example code:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Foo {

    @ParameterizedTestPOJO // Annotation that would generate POJO
    public Foo(String inputString, Integer inputInteger) {
        // Does something
    }

    @Test
    public testSomething() {
        // Tests something
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> generateParameters() {
        List<Object[]> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
        // Example of how generated POJO could be used
        parameters.add(new FooParameterizedPojo("input", 1).getParameters());
        return parameters;
    }

}

// Generated POJO
public class FooParameterizedPojo {
    private String inputString;
    private Integer inputInteger;

    public FooParameterizedPojo(String inputString, Integer inputInteger) {
        this.inputString = inputString;
        this.inputInteger = inputInteger;
    }

    public Object[] getParameters() {
        return new Object[] {inputString, inputInteger};
    }

}
```

Edit: Maybe I could use a custom Lombok annotation? Seems [promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Documentation: `"When a class is annotated with @RunWith or extends a class annotated with @RunWith, JUnit will invoke the class it references to run the tests in that class instead of the runner built into JUnit."` Sounds like something for executing the framework, not running with parameterizing classes.

Comment: I should clarify that there is a method annotated with the @Test annotation that I neglected to add to the Foo class. This is the same use case shown in the official Junit example: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests

Comment: I've fixed the example to include the @Test method.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Read your question 5 times but can not figure what do you actually need? I would suggest you to make first a working example of the normal working parameterized test. Then point what, approximately how &  and why you want to do something with that annotation? I assume you realize that test class is instantiated per param in the static array. Not so that one instance goes through all values in param list. That is why array is static. There is no point to pass param [] to one instance.