# How to create a composite annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

How can I create a composite annotation that applies multiple different annotations to its target? More specifically I want to create a composite of these Lombok annotations:

- `@Getter`
- `@Setter`
- `@AllArgsConstructor`
- `@NoArgsConstructor`

Obviously creating a new `@interface` class and stacking the desired annotations on top of it doesn't work.

Comment: Lombok already has composite annotations, e.g `@Data`; did you look at how they're [implemented](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create custom annotation for Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok)