# Shortcut static final constant declaration with use of lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Is there any way to shortcut java constants declaration with the help of lombok. For example I want to shortcut declaration of

```
public static final String CONST_VALUE = "constant-value";
```

to something like

```
@Constant String CONST_VALUE = "constant-value";
```

Is this possible somehow? Earlier I could shortcut at least `public final` with use of `@FieldDefaults(level = PUBLIC, makeFinal = true)`, but it's [not an option](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1254) anymore. Also I don't want to use `interface` for this purpose, because very often I need 1-2 such fields inside data class, where implementation of interface looks much more redundant. Also one interface for all constant looks like landfill.

Comment: Why is "`public static final`" something you need to avoid? It seems a lot simpler to use a non-magical way to do this.

Comment: You could also [create your own lombok annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `@FieldNameConstants`, but it's experimental feature. [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants)