# remove code duplication in java with custom getter

Tags: java

*This question isnt about selenium, but java in general*

I have the scenario below, while trying to setup an automation framework using selenium and page object model -

```
public class SigninPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    private By emailInputSelector = By.id("user_email");
    private By passwordInputSelector = By.id("user_password");
    private By signinBtnSelector = By.xpath("//input[@value='Log In']");
    private By errorDivSelector = By.xpath("//div[@role='alert']");
    private By headerLinksSelector = By.className("nav-link");

    public SigninPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public WebElement emailInput() {
        return driver.findElement(emailInputSelector);
    }

    public WebElement passwordInput() {
        return driver.findElement(passwordInputSelector);
    }

    public WebElement signinBtn() {
        return driver.findElement(signinBtnSelector);
    }

    public WebElement errorDiv() {
        return driver.findElement(errorDivSelector);
    }

    public List<WebElement> headerElement() {
        return driver.findElements(headerLinksSelector);
    }

}
```

---

as you can see, all my methods like `headerElement()` etc are doing the same thing - `driver.findElement(selector)` or sometimes `driver.findElements(selector)`

I want to remove this code duplication, *like lombok provides `@Getter`*.

What is my best bet to achieve this?

Comment: also, please edit the title of the question if you feel so, I couldnt think of anything better

Comment: I think Page Factory is what you're looking for.

Comment: i tried PageFactory - but I had a problem while using - elements go stale. for e.g. if my page reloads, all elements point to old instances etc...which isn't an issue using this method I think.

Comment: I think the simplest way to slove stale error is writing a WebElement Factory method, input By, return WebElement, or List<WebElement>. If you want a custom lombok annotation, check it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok I don't think it's easy.