# How to run relevant methods using annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok, spring-annotations

Maybe this question title is not up to my queries but I am searching for the answers for so long.

After adding Lombok to a project, we can use getter, setter, Slf4j, etc. Like

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Example {}
```

My query is After adding @Slf4j we can access an instance of a class "log".Like

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
public class Example {

  public void do() {
        log.debug("doing");
    }
}
```

So how can I build this kind of annotation that will provide "log" like implementation in java?

Comment: You want to create a new annotation with a behaviour associated to it ?

Comment: If you want to create a custom annotation in Lombok, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok

Comment: What are you asking exactly? How it works? See https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok. Do not forget that Lombok is like a generated-source-code pre-processor. It will change source code and add some generated code before code is compiled.

Comment: @pringi Just make a simple implementation like Lombok in my way.

Answer (score 2):

Lombok developer here: Lombok is a bit more complicated than that.

Lombok is a unique kind of tool. Yes, it is an annotation processor in the sense that you can specify lombok as being one and lombok then runs as as annotation processor and sets itself up during the `init()` call (`javac` will, once its ready to run the processors, first initialize them all).

Lombok is not an annotation processor in the sense that other than the `init()` step and interacting with the 'rounds' system (specifically: Causing another round to fire in certain cases, in order to ensure `javac` 'sees' the stuff lombok made. Usually this isn't needed, as it takes a little bit of extra time so we don't do it unless absolutely neccessary) – lombok doesn't use the annotation API at all.

If you are asking how to make your own: That's very complicated. Best route is to fork lombok on github, and have a look at e.g. both `HandleSetter.java` files in the source to know what to do (there's one for ecj/eclipse and one for javac). Then, you'll be ready to write your own.

Note that intellij support is done via a separate intellij plugin so if you're interested in having lombok work there, you'd also need to fork that plugin and add support there. You only need to mess with intellij if you want new 'signatures' to be visible (you want to add or remove fields or methods, or you want to change the signature parts of one of those: The name, return type, field type, parameter type, or `throws` line, or you want to add a new type, though that last part can be done with a simple annotation processor).