# add custom code to auto generated setters

Tags: java, lombok

Is there a way to tell Lombok to append a piece of code to each generated setter?
Example:

```
@Setter
public class Foo {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    private void update() { /* ... */ }
}
```

would generate

```
public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
    update();
}

public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
    update();
}
```

Comment: [Create custom annotation for Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok) and [Implementing a Custom Lombok Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation) may be useful

Comment: It is not a good practice to add the execution of logic in your setter.