# How to create an annotation to add a static function to an enum?

Tags: java, enums, annotations, java-11, lombok

Consider the following piece of code:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum Color { 
    RED(1), BLUE(2);
        
    private final int value;
    private static final Map<Integer,Color> mapping = new HashMap<Integer,Color>();

    static {
        for (Color c : Color.values()) {
        mapping.put(c.getValue(), c);
    }
    
    public static Optional<Color> fromValue(int value) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapping.get(value));
    }
}
```

Now if I have to create `fromValue` for multiple such enums, can I create an annotation with the expected result being something like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnumFromValue('int')
public enum Color {
    RED(1), BLUE(2);

    private final int value;
}


....
var maybeColor = Color.fromValue(someInt);
```

Goal to not write the conversion boilerplate for every enum.

1. Is it possible to remove the current value-to-optional conversion boilerplate through annotations?
2. Is it possible through some kind of generics?
3. Is there a simpler method to do this?

Comment: You can do something like that with lombok, but I'm not sure if it's worth your time. Either way you can get more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243018/create-custom-annotation-for-lombok

Comment: Your classes aren’t `enum`s at all. This is an `enum`: `public enum Color { RED, BLUE;
  public static Optional<Color> fromValue(int value) { var v = values(); return value < 1 || value > v.length? Optional.empty(): Optional.of(v[value - 1]); } }` But how many enum types with such an accessor do you have? And what do you need `fromValue` for? Are you about to reinvent `EnumSet`?

Comment: @Holger It's a mistake. Color was an enum. I have marked it as such in the question now.

Comment: Still, my example is simpler without the need for code injection. And your use case unclear…